# Getting the value of radio button to a variable

Tags: jquery

I am not getting the value of radio with name 'monType' button to the variable 'type' . And i need to manipulate 
the variable 'type'.

```
    ('input:radio[name="monType"]').click( function(){
    var type = $("input:radio:checked").val();

    if (type != "") {
        $.post('/sams/monitor/'+type, {
            type : $("input:radio:checked").val(),
            ajax : 'true'
        }, function(data) {
            var html = '';
            $('#lookupValue').html(html);
            var len = data.length;
            for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">'
                        + data[i].name + '</option>';
            }

            $('#lookupValue').append(html);
            $('#lookupValue').trigger('update-select-list').change();
        },
        'json');
    } else {
        var emptyHtml = '';

        $('#lookupValue').html(emptyHtml);
        $('#lookupValue').trigger('update-select-list').change();
   }
 });
```

Please help me.

Comment: can you please provide code in jsfiddle

Comment: `('input:radio[name="monType"]').click...` is that missing something at the beginning? Copy and paste error?

Comment: @PranayRana http://jsfiddle.net/b6x57wz7/

Comment: @user3914290 - check this is updated and working code : http://jsfiddle.net/b6x57wz7/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var type = $("input:radio:checked").val();` will give you the value of the **first** radio button on the entire page that's checked. If you want the checked one with the name `monType` (e.g., the one that's checked *in that group*), you need:

```
var type = $("input:radio[name=monType]:checked").val();
```

However, the `click` event fires on the radio button the user just clicked, and of course clicking the radio button checks it, so you can just do this:

```
var type = this.value; // or $(this).val() if you like, doesn't matter
```

Within the handler, `this` is the DOM element the event relates to, and it will have just been clicked (and checked) by the user, so we know it's this one and can use its value directly.

Answer (score 0):

you missed a `$` at the beginning, also, you can use `this` in your event function:

```
$('input:radio[name="monType"]').click( function(){
    var type = $(this).val();

    if (type != "") {
        $.post('/sams/monitor/'+type, {
            type : type,
            ajax : 'true'
        }, function(data) {
            var html = '';
            $('#lookupValue').html(html);
            var len = data.length;
            for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">'
                        + data[i].name + '</option>';
            }

            $('#lookupValue').append(html);
            $('#lookupValue').trigger('update-select-list').change();
        },
        'json');
    } else {
        var emptyHtml = '';

        $('#lookupValue').html(emptyHtml);
        $('#lookupValue').trigger('update-select-list').change();
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : put `$` sign in the begining and use `$(this)` to get instance of clicked radio button which will give you value of it.

```
$('input:radio[name="monType"]').click( function(){
    var type = $(this).val();

    if (type != "") {
        $.post('/sams/monitor/'+type, {
            type : type,
            ajax : 'true'
        }, function(data) {
            var html = '';
            $('#lookupValue').html(html);
            var len = data.length;
            for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">'
                        + data[i].name + '</option>';
            }

            $('#lookupValue').append(html);
            $('#lookupValue').trigger('update-select-list').change();
        },
        'json');
    } else {
        var emptyHtml = '';

        $('#lookupValue').html(emptyHtml);
        $('#lookupValue').trigger('update-select-list').change();
   }
 });
```